# about Hlookup, but can not show the first line

Tags: excel

I wanna show the level range beside the alphabet, but does not work if I use Hlookup as normal, like the picture.

[image]

Comment: We honestly need to see your Hlookup formula to spot what is wrong.

Comment: I have tried to use 2 formula of Hlookup as below:

Comment: (1)    =HLOOKUP(D20,E$4:H$16,1,FALSE)

Comment: C20 cell will be appeared ---->  #N/A

Comment: (2)    =HLOOKUP("?*",E$4:H$16,1,0)

Comment: C20 cell will be only appeared ---->  LEVEL 1

Comment: Because this formula is only for the first value.

Comment: if D20=B or C, I want C20=LEVEL 1

if D20=D or F or G or H or Z, I want C20=LEVEL 2

if D20=J or O or R or K or P or M or N, I want C20=LEVEL 3

that is what I want.

Comment: I have revised the picture, please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: This answer is based on my little understanding of the question.

I believe you can not (and should not) use Hlookup for this. The Ifs + Match functions should suffice. Paste the following code and drag down
`=IFS(IFERROR(MATCH($B20,$B$8:$B$16,0),0)>0, $B$4, IFERROR(MATCH($B20,$C$8:$C$16,0),0)>0, $C$4,  IFERROR(MATCH($B20,$D$8:$D$16,0),0)>0, $D$4, IFERROR(MATCH($B20,$E$8:$E$16,0), 0)>0, $E$4, IFERROR(MATCH($B20,$F$8:$F$16,0), 0)>0, $F$4)`

See sample pic:
[image]

See sample workbook here at https://1drv.ms/x/s!AklQqQDqhBrtg2uBIiT6InszQqw6?e=1TZx37

Comment: Hi, I have tried to paste your formula into the excel, but it only shown "#NAME?"
Do you know why?

Comment: I think it's because your start column is C while mine is A. I will have to adjust that and get back to you.

Comment: @Cody Please check again as I've updated it. If you are still having any issue let me know.